# John the ripper - "no password hashes loaded " for pdf

Tags: decryption, pdf, john-the-ripper

I'm trying to decrypt a pdf that I no longer have the password for. When I use JohnTheRipper, it can't seem to load any password hashes.
Basically, this is what I run.

```
└─$ perl pdf2john.pl /home/andrew/Desktop/Example.pdf > /home/andrew/Desktop/trial.hash
```

And this runs fine with no output.
I've checked the hash file, and it does exist:

```
┌──(andrew㉿AndrewKali)-[~/JohnTheRipper/run]
└─$ cat /home/andrew/Desktop/trial.hash                                                                                          1 ⨯
/home/andrew/Desktop/Trial.pdf:$pdf$1*2*40*4294967292*1*16*629f7e1f80ac927a176f2098a2f491c7*32*6a6e6a5cc293b11b2780fbcc958aeabb952b12f069e921a1c1d231afd6a9279a*32*22dac1bc2d0a3f0284891227c2b1e67d54180a8d19acfe6143e64264d5e1ceae
```

However, when I try and run `john`, I get:

```
┌──(andrew㉿AndrewKali)-[~/JohnTheRipper/run]
└─$ john /home/andrew/Desktop/trial.hash                                             
Using default input encoding: UTF-8
No password hashes loaded (see FAQ)
```

I know that the tools works, because if I encrypt another pdf, and then use `pdf2john` and then `john`, it works fine:

```
┌──(andrew㉿AndrewKali)-[~/JohnTheRipper/run]
└─$ perl pdf2john.pl /home/andrew/Desktop/working.pdf > /home/andrew/Desktop/working.hash
                                                                                                                                     
┌──(andrew㉿AndrewKali)-[~/JohnTheRipper/run]
└─$ john /home/andrew/Desktop/working.hash
Using default input encoding: UTF-8
Loaded 1 password hash (PDF [MD5 SHA2 RC4/AES 32/64])
Cost 1 (revision) is 4 for all loaded hashes
Will run 4 OpenMP threads
Proceeding with single, rules:Single
Press 'q' or Ctrl-C to abort, almost any other key for status
Warning: Only 1 candidate buffered for the current salt, minimum 8 needed for performance.
Almost done: Processing the remaining buffered candidate passwords, if any.
Warning: Only 7 candidates buffered for the current salt, minimum 8 needed for performance.
Proceeding with wordlist:/usr/share/john/password.lst, rules:Wordlist
12345            (/home/andrew/Desktop/working.pdf)
1g 0:00:00:00 DONE 2/3 (2020-12-21 17:57) 1.063g/s 47156p/s 47156c/s 47156C/s 123456..john
Use the "--show --format=PDF" options to display all of the cracked passwords reliably
Session completed
```

Is it just some issue with the pdf? Do I need to use other tool?

Comment: And you've checked whitespace and newlines, etc.?

Comment: Yes i have checked.

Comment: In your copy/paste of `cat /home/andrew/Desktop/trial.hash`, there's this `1 ⨯` -- what's up with that?